# Why is class constraint not detected for generic class using an inherited type?

Tags: c#, generics, inheritance

Phrasing the question was hard, I hope the following code snippet makes things clear:

```
public class DemoClass<TBase> where TBase : class
{
    public void DemoMethod<T>(T target) where T : TBase
    {
        //The following line causes a design-time error: Type argument 'T' does not satisfy the 'Class' constraint for type parameter 'T'.
        WeakReference<T> demoRef = new WeakReference<T>(target);
    }
}
```

The `WeakReference` requires a type, `T`, that satisfies a `class` constraint. So far, so good, but...

Why can the compiler not detect that `T` actually does, because (practically) `T : TBase : class`?

Comment: Where is the inherited type ? TBase is just an argument which is guaranteed to be a reference type, it has no specific type.

Comment: @SelmanGenç `T` is constrained to be of type `TBase` and `TBase` itself is constrained to be a class type. So `T` itself should be transitively constrained to be a class type.

Comment: @poke that is not true in general. Any `ValueType` inherits from `object` and it most definitely does not comply with `class`.

Comment: @InBetween In that comment I was just explaining OP’s reasoning for this question (which makes sense to me too). I do know that this is not the case though, as explained in my answer below.

Answer (score 5):

> Why can the compiler not detect that T actually does, because (practically) T : TBase : class?

Because that is simply not true. On top of what [Poke](https://stackoverflow.com/users/216074/poke) points out in his [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/44914885/767890), this is also illegal due to the fact that *all value types inherit from* `object`:

```
 var dc = new DemoClass<object>();
 dc.DemoMethod(1); //woops, just attempted to create a WeakReference<int>
```

Your reasoning simply falls apart when value types are involved. Contrived? Yes, but perfectly legal so the compiler doesn't have a choice and has to consider your code illegal.

*UPDATE*

Addressing Jon Hana's comment below that in the code above `T` is not really `int`, its `object` and `1` is boxed implicitly, that is absolutely not true. Consider the following variation of `DemoMethod`:

```
public T DemoMethod<T>(T target) where T : TBase
{
    return target;
}
```

And the following code:

```
var dc = new DemoClass<object>();
var i = dc.DemoMethod(1);
```

`i` is `int`, its not `object`. Moreover, the following will execute correctly:

```
long i = dc.DemoMethod(1);
```

Which also proves the `T` can not be a boxed `int` because the implicit conversion would fail at runtime; you can't unbox a value type to anything but the type itself.

And of course, you can always set `T` explicitly, which also compiles just fine:

```
dc.DemoMethod<int>(1);
```

Comment: @JonHanna That is not true, if you print out `typeof(T)` inside of the method, you can see that it’s `int`.

Comment: @JonHanna That is most definitely not true, see updates in my answer.

Answer (score 4):

Let’s check [the documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/generics/constraints-on-type-parameters) on what `T : class` actually means:

> **`where T : class`**
>
> The type argument must be a reference type; this applies also to any class, interface, delegate, or array type.

Unfortunately, this is already satisfied if `T` is for example an interface. So you can construct a simple example where you can see that applying `T : class` transitively will not work:

```
public interface ITest { }
public struct Test : ITest { }
```

If you now create a `DemoClass<ITest>`, you are satisfying the type constraint since `ITest` is a “class” here. But when you call the method `DemoMethod<Test>`, then you do not have a reference type for `T` although `Test` does inherit `ITest`.

In general, those special generic type constraints do *not* follow the rules of inheritance. That is why they are defined separately and are not already established by the type system. They are there as a special syntax because the type system is not able to express the constaints otherwise.