# Entity Framework Core DbContext.RemoveRange and type constraints

Tags: c#, generics, entity-framework-core

This code throws an exception

> System.InvalidOperationException: The entity type 'List<..>' was not found. Ensure that the entity type has been added to the model.

```
private static void Update<T>(DbContext context, ICollection<T> existing, ICollection<T> updated)  // where T: class
{
      context.RemoveRange(existing); 
      updated.ToList().ForEach(existing.Add);
}
```

However, if you add the type constraint `where T: class` no exception is thrown. Why is this? I was under the impression C# type constraints didn't affect run time behavior like this. Both versions compile fine.

Comment: Check Poke's answer [Here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44914808/why-is-class-constraint-not-detected-for-generic-class-using-an-inherited-type/44914885#44914885)

Answer (score 9, accepted):

It's not the runtime behavior, but the compile time method overload resolution and covariance here:

```
context.RemoveRange(existing);
```

`RemoveRange` method has two overloads:

```
RemoveRange(IEnumerable<object> entities)
```

and

```
RemoveRange(params object[] entities)
```

Having class constraint allows C# compiler to pick the overload with `IEnumerable<object>` - because `ICollection<T>` is `IEnumerable<T>`, and `IEnumerable<T>` for reference type `T` is covariant, hence is `IEnumerable<object>`.

Without class constraint, the only available options is the method with `params object[]` argument. And here comes one of the drawbacks / side effects / traps of `params object[]` construct - every single argument `arg` with type other than `object[]` is treated as `object` and passed implicitly as `new object[] { arg }`.

So, in the former case the actual call is

```
context.RemoveRange((IEnumerable<object>)existing);
```

while in the later case it is

```
context.RemoveRange(new object[] { existing });
```

In other words, the list is passed as object, which leads to the runtime exception in question.

The same applies to all other `Range` methods of the `DbContext` class - `AddRange`, `UpdateRange` and `AttachRange`.

Comment: This is possibly a second question, but from an API design perspective, why does the second overload exist?

Comment: @kayjtea Good question to EF Core API designers :) It allows you to use something like `db.AddRange(new Entrity { }, new Entity { … }, ...)` w/o explicit `new []` - basically the reason `params` modifier exists.